# Did Kayin offer up honey?

Tags: sources-mekorot, parashat-bereishit, fruits, honey

I recall learning somewhere that Kayin's offering was honey, produced from fruit (dates or figs). What is the source for this approach?

Comment: http://www.behindthename.com/name/kayin-1/comments `:-)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this Parsha sheet](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CEMQFjAFahUKEwift_K-08vIAhXKWBQKHTnLBDs&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhalachayomit.com%2Ffarkashpinchas%2Faleh%2FAleh%2520Breisheet%2520III.doc&usg=AFQjCNHGZIFwxH8jyLqE9XQ2YTsLrpkOzw&sig2=wEFINeJu3AfTeAFZ99v3oA&bvm=bv.105454873,d.bGQ&cad=rja), the source is the משך חכמה

> לא קיבל מנחת קין כי היה **דבש** ואסור להקריב שאור ודבש, כי צריך משהו שמעורב בו מעשה אדם כסולת חיטים

Kayin's sacrifice was not accepted because it was from honey...